# manipulate tags in getElementsByTagName loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML `document` with a number of `<code>` tags. I would like to remove the `<code>....</code>`, but not their contents. At first glance

```js
for (element of document.getElementsByTagName("code")) {
    element.outerHTML = element.innerHTML;
}
```

looks alright, but it only replaces every *other* `<code>` element. That's because the element manipulation messes with the `getElementsByTagName`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Use `querySelectorAll('code')` to get a static node list instead of the live node list that `getElementsByTagName`
- Loop over the list backwards to you aren't moving the element you want to touch next into the position you have just finished with.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with the current HTML collection.

```
var lolo = [...document.getElementsByTagName("code")];

for (element of lolo) {
    element.outerHTML = element.innerHTML;
}
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t4ynrfa7/